# How to Hide WhatsApp contact invites

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

So, WhatsApp contacts also displays contacts that don't have WhatsApp account as Invite contact.

How can I hide that Invite Contact list of contacts that don't have WhatsApp account??

I checked the settings and haven't found any option..

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround. 
I changed the details from 'Mobile' to 'Home/Work' in my Android Contacts for all those non-Whatsapp numbers.
Now they don't show up in Whatsapp invite contact.